# SCOM, Server 2008 and SQL Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008, scom

I'm trying to setup SCOM(System Center Operations Manager 2007 (SCOM) – Platform Monitoring) on my Server 2008 machine using SQL Server 2008 running on the same machine. When I check my prerequisites I get problem on SQL and Active Directory components. (I'm running SQL server 2008 and Server 2008 with active directory not installed)

Errors: 
1.Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 1 required.
   **Details**: SQL Server 2005 SP1 is the next version of SQL Server. SQL Server 2005      Enterprise Edition, is a complete data and analysis platform for large mission-critical business applications. The link provided in the resolution column is a trial version of the product and is not supported by the Microsoft SQL Server team

2. In order to install active directory needs to be present.
   **Details**:Setup failed to verify the presence of Active Directory for this server.

I've got a couple of questions I need answering, hope someone can help.

1. Do I need to install Active Directory for SCOM to work?
2. Can I run SCOM with an SQL 2008 Database?
3. How do I get pass these problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Yes. You will need an Active Directory infrastructure available.  SCOM is heavily tied into those services.  It is described further in the Infrastructure section of the [Environmental Prerequisites](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432141.aspx).

2) Yes, but you may need a newer version of SCOM 2007.  The original release version of SCOM does not support SQL 2008 because it didn't exist when it came out.  However, SCOM 2007 R2 does support SQL 2008 with SP1.  Here is the [Operations Manager 2007 R2 Supported Configurations](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb309428.aspx) page.  I think SCOM 2007 SP1 also supports SQL 2008, but you should just start with R2 if you're starting from scratch anyways.

3) Install Active Directory and get media for SCOM 2007 R2 instead of the original release.